# How can I get numbered classes on views rows as static?

Tags: drupal-8

I have numbed a  classes on a view drupal 8 row like

```
<div class="view">

<div class="view-row-1"></div>
<div class="view-row-2"></div>
<div class="view-row-3"></div>
<div class="view-row-4"></div>

</div>
```

I have added some css for view-row-3 but when i delete contents view-row-2 now total rows count should be changed and now view-row-3 became view-row-2 and  view-row-4 became view-row-3 so total css was changed.so i want to re write css

i did the following

select views and

```
Add Global: View result counter and hide it from display

<div class="views-row-{{ counter }}">
</div>
```

Now everything is fine.but if delete  content is is possible  view like

```
<div class="view">

<div class="view-row-1"></div>

<div class="view-row-3"></div>
<div class="view-row-4"></div>

</div>
```

or if i add new content then view like

is it possible?please help me

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use a css selector like:

```
div.view div:nth-child(3) {
  color:red;
}
```